# How can I get the total space memory on linux machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson

I am working on a Nvidia Jetson TX2 device that runs Ubuntu os. I want to build tensorflow c++ api and I need about 14GB memory available space. Is there some linux commands to check my available memory?

Comment: There are many: `free, top, htop, cat /proc/meminfo, vmstat`. If you want GPU information you should use `nvidia-smi`. Sadly this question is not a real Stack Overflow questions and should be directed at [unix.se] or similar.

Answer (score 0):

## Disk Space

To get the free disk space memory in **c++17** you could use the following way:

```cpp
#include <iostream>  

#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::space_info tmp = fs::space("/tmp");

    std::cout << "Free space: " << tmp.free << '\n'
              << "Available space: " << tmp.available << '\n';
}
```

## Memory

These both give information regarding memory in linux:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
```

OR

```
$ less /proc/meminfo
```

And then you could use `grep` to filter out the information that you need:

```java
$ grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
```

Or you could use `c++` and the following function to get the total size (this is specific to **linux** though):

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned long long getTotalSystemMemory()
{
    long pages = sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES);
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    return pages * page_size;
}
```

Comment: In the first case, what is the rows that I am interested to get memory free disk? Second program, I compiled and run, it returns me a number, this is in kb or mb?

Comment: I thought you meant memory and not disk space, check the updated answer.

Comment: I tried your c++ program for free disk space, I got the next error: filesystem:No such file or directory

Comment: Try another directory such as `fs::space("/");` or `fs::space("/home");` and so on

Comment: I got error on #include <filesystem> line

Comment: Then you are not using c++17 and above, can you use another version of c++?